# javascript statement identifying one value

Tags: javascript, listener, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am having an issue with getting my trusted ip address's to work - I can get IP1 to work how it should however the rest just divert back to the holding page - what have I missed?

**Code:**

```
  addEventListener("fetch", event => {
      event.respondWith(fetchAndReplace(event.request))
    })
     
    async function fetchAndReplace(request) {
     
      let modifiedHeaders = new Headers()
     
      modifiedHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'text/html')
      modifiedHeaders.append('Pragma', 'no-cache')
    
      // Allow users through if they are bypass flag and set a cookie
      if(request.url.includes("bypass"))
      {
        // Forward request to origin, get response.
        let response = await fetch(request)
    
        // Copy Response object so that we can edit headers.
        response = new Response(response.body, response)
        
        // set a cookie for the session
        response.headers.set("Set-Cookie", "cf:maintenance-mode=bypass");
        
        // Return on to client.
        return response
      }
    
      // Allow users through if they have the bypass cookie
      // Check for cookie.
      let cookies = request.headers.get('Cookie') || ""
      if (cookies.includes("cf:maintenance-mode=bypass")) {
        // User has been here before. Just pass request through.
        return fetch(request)
      }
    
      //Return maint page if you're not calling from a trusted IP
      
      var connectionIP = request.headers.get("cf-connecting-ip")
    
    if (connectionIP != "ip1" || connectionIP != "ip2" || connectionIP != "ip3") { 
        // Return modified response.
        return new Response(maintPage, {
          headers: modifiedHeaders
        })
      }
       //Allow users from trusted into site
      else
      {
        //Fire all other requests directly to our WebServers
        return fetch(request)
      }
    }
     
    let maintPage = `
     
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Site Maintenance</title>
    <style>
      body { 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 150px; 
            background: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,<base64EncodedImage>'); 
            background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
          }
     
        .content {
            background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75); 
            background-size: 100%;      
            color: inherit;
            padding-top: 1px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-left: 100px;
            padding-right: 100px;
            border-radius: 15px;        
        }
     
      h1 { font-size: 40pt;}
      body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
      article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 75%; margin: 0 auto; }
      a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }  
     
     
    </style>
     
    <article>
     
            <div class="background">
                <div class="content">
            <h1>We&rsquo;ll be back soon!</h1>        
                <p>We're very sorry for the inconvenience but we&rsquo;re performing maintenance. Please check back soon...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
     
    </article>`;
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the wrong logic operators.

Let's say `connectionIP` is `ip1`.

```
connectionIP != "ip1" || connectionIP != "ip2" || connectionIP != "ip3"
-> "ip1" != "ip1" || "ip1" != "ip2" || "ip1" != "ip3"
-> false || true || true
-> true

// Or if it's ip2...
-> "ip2" != "ip1" || "ip2" != "ip2" || "ip2" != "ip3"
-> true || false || true
-> true

// Or if it's something else...
-> "different" != "ip1" || "different" != "ip2" || "different" != "ip3"
-> true || true || true
-> true
```

No matter what `connectionIP` is, it's always going to evaluate to `true` because it's always going to not equal one of the values in the list.

What you actually want is `&&`

```
connectionIP !== "ip1" && connectionIP !== "ip2" && connectionIP !== "ip3"
-> "ip1" !== "ip1" && "ip1" !== "ip2" && "ip1" !== "ip3"
-> false && true && true
-> false

// Or if it's ip2...
-> "ip2" !== "ip1" && "ip2" !== "ip2" && "ip2" !== "ip3"
-> true && false && true
-> false

// Or if it's something else...
-> "different" !== "ip1" && "different" !== "ip2" && "different" !== "ip3"
-> true && true && true
-> true
```

The logic may be easier to follow and more maintainable if you use a `Set`:

```
const internalAddresses = new Set(["ip1", "ip2", "ip3"]);

// ...

return internalAddresses.has(connectionIP)
  ? fetch(request) 
  : new Response(maintPage, { headers: modifiedHeaders })
```

Comment: I understood everything up-until the set :).  I can't see to get it to work - I am also trying to exclude linode servers to use wget to transfer a site but this should not make a difference should it?

Comment: Are you able to help with the above?

Comment: I need more specific details than "can't seem to get it to work." It might be easiest to get answers if you post that as a separate question. If you link that question here I can try to get to it (or someone else in the community may if I'm not available).